# Is it safe to read a dangerous website with urllib

Tags: python-3.x

Some websites can be dangerous and I would like to see if I can understand why this is so. I've understood that such sites are considered risky since they run malicious JavaScripts. I wonder if it is safe to open a dangerous site with urllib. I've written the following code which tries to print the source code of a user input website to the screen. I would like to know if the following would lead to any critical issues

```
import urllib
from urllib import request

url = input('URL:\n')

x = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
raw = x.read()

try:
    print(raw.decode('utf-8'))
except Exception as e:
    print(type(e), e)
    if type(raw) == bytes:
        print(raw.decode('latin-1'))
```

Comment: If your question is *"does `urllib` execute JavaScript"*, then: no, it doesn't. Indeed there are many questions on SO from people who didn't realise how this would affect their attempts to scrape web pages.

Comment: But that doesn't mean that the code that *you* have written is safe or secure.

Comment: Running eval on data from an untrusted source is definitely not safe, why are you using it?

Comment: It seems to me that for any variable v, if type(v) == bytes, then eval(str(v)[1:]) == v.decode('latin-1'). This is because str(v), if v is a bytes object, starts with the character b and whatever comes after it can be interpreted as a string. What if I change the last line, print(eval(str(raw)[1:])) to print(raw.decode('latin-1'))?

Answer (score -1):

We may underline the fact that each time you visit a website, the website (via the access.log) & your ISP (transparent proxy log + routeur log) & probably also your governement (via some massive surveillance program) have to keep traces of your visit - at least timestamp, your public IP adress and the URL you visited-

The public IP address could be from this point of view the start point to potential malicious/dangerous things to do (a Man in Middle attack for example).

If you know and assume that, I can confirm that HTML code (which potentially contain some Javascript code too) cannot be dangerous until the JS code will be interpreted somewhere.

Best regards.